# SlateJS internal copy feature not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slatejs

Have been trying to build an open-source notion using #slatejs, not been able to find why the internal copy is not working on my editor.

Multiple selections also just shows the last element in selection rather than showing all the elements selected.

Pops up this error when I press `ctrl + c`:
[image: copy error]

Tried selecting the children element using `editor.children[editor.selection.anchor.path[0]]` but it just logs the last element selected and not all of them.

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you :)

Comment: Can you please provide a codesandbox or any example code we can run locally?

Comment: The code is open-sourced, here is the [code for slate editor](https://github.com/manthankumbhar/frontend_open-source-notion/blob/master/src/components/SlateEditor/SlateEditor.js) and [live site](https://open-source-notion.manthankumbhar.com/) @esp